# How to compare string from a csv file servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, csv

I am doing a answer servlet with a csv file. This servlet works as a answer bank where in the user puts the start year and end year. Then he will choose from the radio buttons. My code should get the answer from the csv file that contains from the start to end year and which team has the most wins/loss. I use a simple array to contain the values from the csv file.  I tried the out.print method( as you can see below), to check if it does store in the array, however all data from that column is stored.How can I compare the users input such as the year to a specific year from the array

Edit again: I added the for loop that compares the users' string input to the array values. Am I doing it right? I want to compare the string to input to a value from values[0]
Example:

Year:
from________to_________

(radio button) Most wins
(radio button) most loss

code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        /*
        //out.println(request.getParameter("start"));
        //out.println(request.getParameter("end"));
      String str = request.getParameter("stat");
*/

    String csvFile = "C:/Users/j_oer_000/Desktop/servlet/baseballstats.csv";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";
    String[] values = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null)   {
        values = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
        out.print(values[8]);
        out.print("</br>");
    }
if(start.compareTo(startYear) >=1871 || end.compareTo(startYear) <=2013)    {
        for(int i = 0; i < values[0].length(); i++) {
         if(start == values[0].charAt(i))   {
             wins=values[8].charAt(i);
             loss=values[9].charAt(i);

         }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want to compare all the values in the csv file with the "stat" value. If yes then you will have to parse the excel with some 3rd party tools like apache poi which are specifically for this purpose.

Comment: for example if the user puts the year from "2009" to 2011", and picks the radio button for most wins, then it should get the wins from the team with the most win from 2009 to 2011

Comment: the csv file contains all the statistical data of all the teams from 1871 to 2013.